# How do you chain beforeInterceptors together?

Tags: inheritance, grails, interceptor

I have a controller that inherits from a class with a `beforeInterceptor`.

Here is my base class.

```
class FooBase {
    def beforeInterceptor = [action: {parentInterceptor()}]

    def parentInterceptor() {
        render("Snarge")
    }
}
```

Here is the version of the controller that does not work.

```
class BrokenController extends FooBase
{
    def beforeInterceptor = [action: {childInterceptor()}]

    def childInterceptor() {
        super.beforeInterceptor.action.call()
        render("Bar")
    }

    def index = {
        render("Foo")
    }
}
```

Here is a version that *does* work

```
class WorkingController extends FooBase
{
    def beforeInterceptor = {
        super.beforeInterceptor.action.call()
        render("Bar")
    }

    def index = {
        render("Foo")
    }
}
```

When I call index on `WorkingController`, I get the output `SnargeBarFoo`.  When I call index on `BrokenController` I get an `IllegalAccessError`

I suppose I have a version that works, so my question is more about what is going on here?  Why can one version access the parent class from the child class, but the other cannot?

The use case I'm looking for is being able to use the interceptor functions with the `except` functionality.  That requires being able to chain interceptors when they are implemented using a map.

Comment: Do you get solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between

```
this.
```

and

```
this.&
```

the following code works - check the third line:

```
class BrokenController extends FooBase
{
    def beforeInterceptor = [action: {this&childInterceptor()}]

    def childInterceptor() {
        super.beforeInterceptor.action.call()
        render("Bar")
    }

    def index = {
        render("Foo")
    }
}
```

The documentation states the following aboit this.&

```
Method Reference     .&      Get a reference to a method, can be useful for creating closures from methods
```

So I am not sure, but I guess it has something todo with the scope the method is invoked in. Maybe the system creates some kind of helper class in order to execute a closure which results in this class not having the super.beforeInterceptor method.